# validate the access token obtained from the linkedin Rest API

Tags: rest, oauth, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I have a mobile application talking to a backend. I am providing login to the app through LinkedIn. I checked the linkedIn api for oauth authentication and have followed the steps as given in this link
[Oauth LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2).

I am able to obtain the request token as per step 3. Now i am sending this request to my backend. In the backend i want to make sure that this request token is valid and has not expired.

How do i achieve this ? In FB authentication, they have provided an end point to which i post the access token `(https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=)`and it gives the expiry time, validity of token etc.

How do we do this with LinkedIn api, i searched their documentation, but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no separate API that LinkedIn provides to inspect the token. However you do get a hint about the token expiry back in the response from the token endpoint when exchanging the `code` for an `access_token` in the `expires_in` parameter, e.g.:

```
   {"access_token":"<>","expires_in":5183999}
```

which tells you that it is valid for 60 days. You could store that information together with the access token.

Comment: Thanks. I did see these paramters being returned along with access token. I thought similar to G+ and FB API even linkedin might have some separate REST end point to validate. Looks like it does not. Cool i will use the response and store the same. Thanks again.

Comment: I believe they answered this here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115035/how-can-i-verify-a-linkedin-access-token

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Token Introspection" endpoint to check the validity of your access token at any time.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/token-introspection. Use Refresh token to refresh it before it expires.