# How can I verify a LinkedIn access token?

Tags: linkedin-api

**How can I verify a LinkedIn access token?**

I need to check if an access token is valid or not?

ex: in Facebook

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=access_token
```

Is there a similar way to do it in LinkedIn?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that it can be done like this:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN
```

and that's it :).

Comment: It's not working to me, If you don't mind, could you tell me updated solution.

Comment: Working for me, you can also check the company pages the token allows access to:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true&oauth2_access_token=YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, you can filter the values:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,location,industry,current-share,num-connections,summary,specialties,positions)?format=json&oauth2_access_token={0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Token Introspection to get some informations about the token

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/token-introspection?context=linkedin/context

Comment: Hello! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

The url has been changed and the v1 API does not work anymore. Do use this one, if you need to verify access tokens generated from Linkedin.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token=<your-token-here>
```

For other social media's, use can use urls from this gist: https://gist.github.com/pavittarx/15b46b08e779c2113864e9db399f35ac