# 403 Forbidden Access to posting shares denied for Linkedin API using python-linkedin library

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, linkedin-api

I'm new to working with the Linkedin API and I'm trying to post to LinkedIn using the python-linkedin library: https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin

We use Auth0 for authentication.
I can get profile information. However, I get a 403 error when trying to post using the Share API.

Testing get profile in the shell works:

```
In []: linkedin_api.get_profile()
Out[]:
{'firstName': '*my name*',
 'headline': '*my headline*',
 'id': '*my id*',
 'lastName': '*my lastname*',
 'siteStandardProfileRequest': {'url': 'https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=*CONFIDENTIAL*&authType=name&authToken=*CONFIDENTIAL*'}}
```

However when I try to post to linkedin:

```
In []: linkedin_api.submit_share('Test posting
...: from the API I am working on using JSON'
...: , 'A title for your share', None, 'http:
...: //www.linkedin.com', 'http://d.pr/3OWS')
```

This results in a 403 Client Error

```
LinkedInForbiddenError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: 
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?
oauth2_access_token=*CONFIDENTIAL*: Access to posting shares denied
```

Comment: Most likely did you generate the access token correctly? That will cause these kinds of issues

Comment: it should be correct. I followed the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115035/how-can-i-verify-a-linkedin-access-token to verify the access token is working.

also, the access token is generated with auth0 by getting the associated Auth0  Linkedin Profile then retrieving the access token so since it's handled by Auth0 I don't think there'd be an issue. I've checked Auth0 to make sure that permissions are set correctly as well

Comment: Actually I think you may be correct. I just tried authenticating on the shares route `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares/?oauth2_access_token=*Confidential*` rather than the profile route and I was denied access! I'm going to look into why that may be and post if I find anything

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was wrong.

I needed to add the w_share scope in my auth0 lock so that I'd have access to the linkedin Share api.

here's a link to a question that helped me out: https://community.auth0.com/t/linkedin-w-share-permission/12386/2

I added the connectionScopes param to the auth0 lock options and that solved the issue:

```
connectionScopes: {
    linkedin: ["w_share"]
}
```